# Docker - how to automatically POST a request on a REST container after launch?

Tags: post, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a docker container that is part of a big project configured and launched by `docker-compose`. This container needs configuration when it is started by sending it an HTTP POST request to its REST API.

Basically what I do now is that I run `docker-compose up` and wait a bit so that everything seems to have started, and particularly the given docker container. Then I send my HTTP POST with a `curl` command.

Is there a way to modify the `Dockerfile` so that it will launch the Docker container, wait for its REST API to be up and POST a given request?

---

My question is a generic one but if you need more details, here is my current very simple `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM 1ambda/kafka-connect:latest
COPY my-project/target/*.jar $KAFKA_HOME/libs/
```

And the corresponding line in the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
connect:
    build: kafka-connect
    links:
      - kafka
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
        CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092
        CONNECT_GROUP_ID: connect-cluster-A
```

And finally the HTTP POST I do once the container is up:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '
{ 
"name":"my-project",
"config" : 
    {
    "name":"my-project",
    "topics":"my-topic",
    "tasks.max":2,
    "connector.class":"the.package.to.my.connector.class"
    }
}
' http://localhost:8083/connectors
```

Comment: Docker has no waiting/polling mechanism built in. You could wrap sending the POST request in a script, that polls the API (`/status` or something) and sends the request as soon as the API is up.
Docker 1.12 introduced the [`HEALTHCHECK`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck) instruction where you could do the polling of the API. But in this case it would be easier to build it into the API.

Comment: After reading your question again: If it's okay to send the POST request from within the container, `HEALTHCHECK` could be the way to go. But than the POST request will be sent multiple times (if you don't wrap it in some fancy logic again)

Comment: @mgansler, thank you for your comments. I have not used HEALTHCHECK yet but I thought it was rather to create a command to be launched every once in a while in order to check if the container is running well and to kill it or restart it otherwise. But I will investigate in this direction.

Otherwise, I thought at creating a custom script that I could launch at container startup that waits for the REST API to answer to then POSTs my data, but I don't know how to launch such a script at the same time as the ENTRYPOINT of the FROM image of my container...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create another container that wait for the the rabbitmq to expose its REST API and then perform the actions you want (Sending the HTTP POST in your case)

Here is an example of the docker-compose file

```yml
connect:
    build: kafka-connect
    links:
      - kafka
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
        CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092
        CONNECT_GROUP_ID: connect-cluster-A

connect-init:
    build:
        context: .
    depends_on:
        - connect
    links:
        - connect
    command: ["/wait-for-it.sh", "-t", "300", "connect:8083", "--", "/init.sh"]
```

Here is the Docker file for the init container. You can use this [wait-for-it.sh](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/blob/master/wait-for-it.sh) file

```
FROM bash
RUN apk add --no-cache curl
ADD init.sh wait-for-it.sh /
```

And the init.sh file contains your HTTP POST (You can add other commands to this file if you need)

```sh
curl -X POST \
    http://connect:8083/connectors \
    -d '{"name":"my-project","config":{"name":"my-project","topics":"my-topic","tasks.max":2,"connector.class":"the.package.to.my.connector.class"}}'
```

Comment: Since this was ages ago, I cannot test your answer but if I remember correctly I ended up doing something very similar to this (I did use the very same wait-for-it bash script).

Comment: I have just faced that issue and found your question while I was trying to resolve it. I fixed it with the method I mentioned above. I knew that you will surely not be in need of the solution but thought it maybe of benefits to other users.

Comment: I had to add this line to the end od the Dockerfile: RUN chmod +x /init.sh because I was getting permission error. The file is then runnable and there is no error anymore. Other than that, it works! Thanks a lot for your code.